# PHP-HTML-ORACLE i have an error on a script

Tags: php, html, sql, oracle

Hi guys i'm a beginner with php and html can u help me to solve this problem?

It gives me this error `Warning: oci_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php on line 15`

this is my code :

```
<?php 
session_start();
// connect to database
if (isset($_POST['login_btn'])) {
    $username =$_POST['username'];
    $password =$_POST['password'];
    $conn = oci_connect('socialdb', '12345', 'localhost/XE');
    if (!$conn) {
        $e = oci_error();
        trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    $password = md5($password); // remember we hashed password before storing last time
    $sql = oci_parse($conn,"SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
    $result =oci_execute($sql);
    if (oci_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "You are now logged in";
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header("location: home.php"); //redirect to home page
    } else{
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Username/password combination incorrect";
    }
}
?>
```

UPDATE:Maybe the problem is in the HTML form :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Register, login and logout user php oracle</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylea.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header"> 
 <h1>Register, login and logout user php oracle</h1>
</div>
<?php
 if (isset($_SESSION['message'])) {
  echo "<div id='error_msg'>".$_SESSION['message']."</div>";
  unset($_SESSION['message']);
 }
?>


<form method="post" action="login.php">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>Username:</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="username" class="textInput"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td>Password:</td>
   <td><input type="password" name="password" class="textInput"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td><input type="submit" name="login_btn" value="Login"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: please check your sql on db first "SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'". check that are you getting results for given user and password or not. or u may have more then 1 row for this sql.

Comment: 1 have just 1 row in my table and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check query result validity first, then pay attention since oci_execute returns a boolean, refer to [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-num-rows.php) for an example

```
$result = oci_execute($sql);
if ($result) {
    if (oci_num_rows($sql) == 1) {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "You are now logged in";
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header("location: home.php"); //redirect to home page
    } else{
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Username/password combination incorrect";
    }
} else {
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Query error";
}
```

Comment: i still have this Warning: oci_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php on line 16

Comment: Now it works but if i insert the right "username" and "password" it gives me that they r incorrect, can u help me?:D I tryed the select form the db and it works

Comment: Are you sure `$username` and `$password` variables content is right? Are you sure `oci_num_rows()` doesn't return a number > 1?

Comment: I'm sure i use the same variables,i have just 2 rows in my table but with different username.I use an html form for the input maybe is there the problem?

Comment: Please echo `$sql` content and post it

Comment: i tryed and it gives me just 1 row

Comment: I'm not talking about executing query on db, you should echo it from php. So can you echo `oci_num_rows($sql)` result?